# Start .exe with Batch file and several parameters

Tags: batch-file

I need to start a program and hand over several parameters to the .exe but don't get it working with .bat-File.

I Also tried to set the whole path including parameters in "", but doesn't help.

Where is my Mistake? If using

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Software\ameise.exe" --server=(local)\FILES --database=baset_1 --dbuser=sa --dbpass=asdasd+13da# --templateid=EXP6 --outputfile=C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\DATA.csv
```

All alone without start "" command in a .bat file without if condition, it works perfectly fine.
Also the if conditions work perfectly only with "echo test".
But adding the program line to the condition will let the CMD window close immediately after start of the .bat file.

Where is my mistake?
Tank you for your help!

```
@echo off

set var1=1
set var2=1

IF %var1%==1 (
    start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Software\ameise.exe" --server=(local)\FILES --database=baset_1 --dbuser=sa --dbpass=asdasd+13da# --templateid=EXP6 --outputfile=C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\DATA.csv
)

IF %var2%==1 (
    echo test
)
Pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's remove the parenthesis as you are running single command, though they cause not harm. Then put the if statement commands in single line.

Use `equ` over `==` have a look at `if /?` for more on that. Also, I always enclose my if variables with double quotes.. in case some scary whitespace creeps in there.

So please try this, untested, as I do not have your command available:

```
@echo off
set var1=1
set var2=1

if "%var1%" equ "1" start "" /wait "C:\Program Files (x86)\Software\ameise.exe" --server=(local)\FILES --database=baset_1 --dbuser=sa --dbpass=asdasd+13da# --templateid=EXP6 --outputfile=C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\DATA.csv
if "%var2%" equ "1" echo test
Pause
```

Edit, add `/wait` to the start command if you want them in sequence. See code edit above.

Comment: My Pleasure. Glad it helped :)

Comment: Hey - wow, that helped a lot! Thank you, now it works!
I am pretty new to batch scripting... and now I noticed that two command line windows open. One is showing the .exe working and the other only shows "push button ...". No echo notice.

Comment: it is because you start the program. Perhaps remove the entire `start "" /wait` portion and let it issue the command itself.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!

Comment: Using `IF` without parenthesis, while effective in this particular case, just hides the fact of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one and see if it works.

```
@echo off

set var1=1
set var2=1

if "%var1%" == "1" (
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Software\ameise.exe" --server=^(local^)\FILES --database=baset_1 --dbuser=sa --dbpass=asdasd+13da# --templateid=EXP6 --outputfile=C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\DATA.csv
)
if "%var2%" == "1" (
    echo.Test
)
pause>nul
```

Comment: This is wrong, did you even test it? how will `"1"` be equal to `1`

Comment: I guess my answer is obsolete as you already wrote yours. Sorry.

Comment: No, it is not, but not much changed from the original, your answer was wrong, which you edited now.

Comment: You just need to escape the closing paren in `--server=(local)\FILES` ---> `--server=(local^)\FILES` because it conflicts the parenthesis of the `IF` block. The string containing `Program Files (x86)` has no issue because it is surrounded by quotes; Otherwise your answer is correct. That was the root cause of the issue OP had in their question.